# find out the origin of function calls

Tags: c, linux

I wonder if there is a software that can help us determine all possible origins of a function call. 
For example:

```
/* in file f1.c */
int f1() {
 x_func();
}

/* in file f2.c */
int f2() {
 x_func();
}
```

If we want to trace the origin of all function calls to x_func(), the output will be:

```
f1.c:f1()
f2.c:f2()
```

This is very useful when reading the source code. 
All answers are appreciated. Thank in advance :D

Comment: Most IDE's can do this. Have a look at Eclipse, for example.

Comment: If your functions had better names, `grep` would do fine.

Comment: Thank everyone for taking time answer my question :">

Comment: @user560343:  The way to show appreciation here is to up-vote and/or accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) will do that for you (with pictures!).

Also many IDEs also incorporate such capabilities Visual Studio for example will generate textual call graphs as well as having a "find all references" search.  You can do this with the free VC++ Express Edition, the project need not be a VC++ project to use its code navigation features, just create a makefile project and add the header file paths to the preprocessor settings.

Answer (score 2):

[cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) can help here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to the this at runtime any debugger will be able to do that: just place a breakpoint within `x_func` and print the stack trace any time it pauses.

Comment: I think the OP wants a static analysis to find out all possible points of arrival

Comment: @David Heffernan: may be. OP wasn't explicit enough and since there were already two good answers about static analysis, I offered one about dynamic analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Tagfile programs, such as ctags and etags, do this.  They're written to work with editors rather than to be specifically human readable.  Emacs's M-. key looks things up in the tagfile.